# jQuery conflict on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5.1, jquery-rails

My `application.js`:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require flatpickr.min
//= require_tree .
```

My `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

If I
I just leave my app like that, all my jQuery will work fine. But I also need

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"</script>
</head>
```

on my `application.html.erb` since I am using Bootstrap 4.

So with this configuration, I am experiencing lot of issues with my jQuery, like

> $(...).flatpickr is not a function

Is there a way to avoid those conflicts?
I suppose that's because I'm including multiple *jQueries* on my app.

If I remove `//= require jquery` all the Bootstrap-related jQuery will work, but my custom scripts won't.
If I remove `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"</script>` my scripts will work but all Bootstrap-related won't (like the hamburger navbar or similars).

Comment: Bootstrap-sass is for bootstrap 3. Are you importing bootstrap4 from the cdn on top of the bootstrap-sass gem?

Comment: @GiorgioZanni if i remove the `bootstrap-sass` gem, I get a `Sass::SyntaxError -> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.`

Comment: What I meant is to ask why do you say that you're using bootstrap 4, when you are importing a bootstrap 3 gem?
Try `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2.1'` instead of `bootstrap-sass`. In any case, you don't need to include jquery inside your `<head>` tag. If you're using bootstrap's gem, it will work with the jquery gem, otherwise, if you're using the CDN, jquery's cdn needs to be placed just before your closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to add bootstrap 4 to your rails 5 application here are the links to [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap) and [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) pages.

Step 1: Add bootstrap and jquery-rails to your Gemfile(Ensure that sprockets-rails is at least v2.3.2)

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Step 2: Add Bootstrap dependencies and Bootstrap to your application.js

```
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
```

You don't need to specify the cdn of jquery on your views that's the function of the line //= require jquery3. And remove your bootstrap-sass dependency which is for [bootstrap 3](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass)

**Note:** Important to notice that you need to require jquery3 with **//= require jquery3**